# Change width of median line of boxenplot in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm using seaborn for an EDA
and I'm having an issue to easily identify the median line in the plots.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxenplot(x=tips["total_bill"],color="paleturquoise")
```

the default result looks like this:

[image]

And depending on the plot it gets harder to identify it, I have tried several colors but the options I have on that regard are just a few for the format of the report.

So the solution would the to make that line a bit wider so it gets easier to find, but I have not found any option to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the median line parameters by using `ax.lines[0]` methods:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxenplot(x=tips["total_bill"], color="paleturquoise", linewidth=0.8)
l = ax.lines[0]

# set median line style
l.set_linestyle(':')
l.set_color('r')
l.set_linewidth(5)
l.set_alpha(1)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: result]